# CORS issue with calling an API using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xml, cors

I'm trying to call an `API` which returns `XML` data in response.

When I run that .htm file on my local machine, it gives me the following **error**.
[image: Calling from local machine]

And, when running it from the `codepen.io` platform, it gives me the following **error**.
[image: Calling from codepen platform]

But, when I call the API from [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com) or [JSON Formatter](https://jsonformatter.org/xml-viewer), it works gives the response. When I simply paste it in the browser and hit Enter, it works there too. But not working with my code. I'm not sure what's the problem. Can anyone please help me?

Here's my **code**:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>jQuery.parseXML demo</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <p id="someElement">Hello</p>
    <p id="anotherElement"></p>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var api_url = 'http://lb.50g.nl/xml/29474bb065f2b30ca5eb3496f231bced.xml'

            $.ajax({
                url: api_url + $(this).text(),
                dataType: "xml",
                async: true,
                method: "GET",
                headers: {
                    "accept": "text/xml",
                    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
                },
                crossDomain: true,
                success: function (result) {
                    console.log(result);
                }
            })
        });

    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: double check the datatype you insert in postMan and compare that one with the the data you insert in browser etc. compare those you will find the difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

API Gateway from AWS will help you solve this all day long.

When you run an HTTP request it's a good practice to call a module from the back end (with js/node) this will get you around the CORS issue. but why set up a server/back-end when you can use AWS for it.

with a few extra steps you can make an API that passes the request and then call that from your browser where it will send your page a cross domain allowed response.

see my answer here:

[How to retrieve cross origin volcanic data in xml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55231697/how-to-retrieve-cross-origin-volcanic-data-in-xml/57940455#57940455)

Answer (score 3):

What you are seeing has something to do with what is called CORS.

In essence, you are not allowed to request resources from an other server ( domain ) than the one your document is served from.
This is to help mitigate risks of xSite attacks.

The API is working just fine, that is why postman gets you the data, it is actually the browser forbidding the request from been fired from your document.

In order to request resources from a different domain than the one you are serving you have to enforce some security policies.

You can take a look in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5750696/how-to-get-a-cross-origin-resource-sharing-cors-post-request-working) for more info.

Comment: This may help me, but I'm not a pro developer. Still figuring out what exactly I have to do. :)

Comment: Try to follow the answer given by 'Miracool' on the link i posted, it should let you hit the API normally from your page. If not let me know again

Comment: Yes, I tried that. Getting the same errors. I'm still trying to figure it out. :)

Answer (score 1):

I totally agree with `MKougiouris`. you are getting the error as a result of `Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS)`. so your back end reject any `API` call that is not from the same origin eg `server`. CORS help you restrict access to some resources from a specified origin. how ever if you are the one that is managing the back-end you can use this code to give access to all origin. `header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*")`. but this worked for my node project.

```
app.all('*', function(req, res, next) {
  var origin = req.get('origin'); 
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', origin);
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
  res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
  next();
})
```

Note: if you are working on a confidential project you should restrict access but the above give access to all.