# Angular No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'

Tags: javascript, android, angular, cors

I'm building a ionic+angular app for listing euromillions results, and I'm trying get data by external api, I don't want to use a server, it's just for listing the api results, but I'm getting the cors block, and I dont know how to resolve this, can someone help me? Thanks

lotteries.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule, HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Euromillions } from './lottery.model';


@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LotteriesService {
    private euromillions: Euromillions[] = [
        {
            id: 'r1',
            numbers: '6-14-22-37-45',
            stars: '3-7',
            draw_info: 'Sorteio Nº076, 22-10-2019'
        }
    ];
    constructor(private httpService: HttpClient) { }

    getLastEuromillions() {
        return [...this.euromillions];
    }

    getApi() {

        return this.httpService.get('https://nunofcguerreiro.com/api-euromillions-json');
    }
}
```

lotteries.page.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { Euromillions } from './lottery.model';
import { LotteriesService } from './lotteries.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-lotteries',
  templateUrl: './lotteries.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./lotteries.page.scss'],
})
export class LotteriesPage implements OnInit {
  euromillions: Euromillions[];

  constructor(private lotteriesService: LotteriesService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.lotteriesService.getApi().subscribe((data)=>{
      console.log(data);
    }
    )};
}
```

[image error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wpfcu.png)

Answer (score 1):

The external browser blocks your request. 
you have two choices.
either using the back-end to receive the request and redirect it.
Or the API owner allows the cross-origin.
read this link for more details
[mozila reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)

Answer (score 1):

API Gateway from AWS will help you solve this all day long.

When you run an HTTP request it's a good practice to call a module from the back end (with js/node) this will get you around the CORS issue. but why set up a server/back-end when you can use AWS for it.

with a few extra steps you can make an API that passes the request and then call that from your browser where it will send your page a cross domain allowed response.

see my other answer here:
  [How to retrieve cross origin volcanic data in xml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55231697/how-to-retrieve-cross-origin-volcanic-data-in-xml/57940455#57940455)

Comment: wow man this works very well so easy to do thanks very much super easy solution :D

Comment: cool, yeah i know. make sure to mark the question as the answer if it solved the problem, just click the check-mark. best!